# Why Odoo is adding aria-hidden = "true" attribute to icons in html?

Tags: rendering, odoo, qwebview, qweb, odoo-website

```
<h6 id="college" data-toggle="tooltip" title="College">
    <i t-ignore="True" aria-hidden="false" class="fa fa-university"></i><t t-raw="person.college.name"/>
</h6>
```

Above is a line of code I am writing and see how it is rendering, the icon is hidden. May I please know the reasons?

```
<h6 id = "college" data-toggle = "tooltip" title = "College"> 
    <i aria-hidden = "true" class = "fa fa-university"> </i> College of Science and Technology 
</ h6 >
```